# Change dragView during drag with JavaFX

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop

-- EDIT

I just found out that it is not possible, but is there anything else I can do to generate visuals like I want?

I'm using JavaFX to set a dragView on the DragBoard, but I can't seem to find a way to change that image during a drag operation.

I've tried to use `setDragView(MyImage)` when the drag over event was fired, but that didn't work.

Is this at all possible, or should I find another way?

Code below:

```
// Called when drag starts
public void handleBlockDragDetected(PuzzleBlockView puzzleBlockView, PuzzleBlock puzzleBlock, GridPane blockPane)
{
    ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
    clipboardContent.put(GameController.BLOCK_FORMAT, puzzleBlock);

    Dragboard dragboard = blockPane.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);
    dragboard.setDragViewOffsetX(20);
    dragboard.setDragViewOffsetY(20);
    dragboard.setDragView(puzzleBlockView.getSnapshot());
    dragboard.setContent(clipboardContent);

    blockPane.setVisible(false);
    draggingBlock = puzzleBlockView;
}

// Called on dragOver detected
public void handleBlockDragOver(DragEvent event)
{
    Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();

    if (dragboard.hasContent(BLOCK_FORMAT) && draggingBlock != null) {
        dragboard.setDragView(new Image(getClass().getResource("/img/flag.png").toString()));

        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to indicate to the user the current target can accept the drop? If so, you could style the `Node` differently.

Comment: I want to change the dragView image to display on which tile inside the block collides with another tile on the grid.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.